# Perform fetch without freezing the UI

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm making a small chat app. In my app I'm using NSFetchedResultsController. There are 2 tableViews, 1 for lobby and 1 for the chat room. The problem is that whenever I enter a chat room I have to wait for NSFetchedResultsController to perform fetch and load all the data before I can start typing anything. I was wondering if it's possible to preform fetch in background or somehow let the user start typing before the last messages are loaded.

So if I set that part in viewDidLoad method, my UI just freezes until all the data is loaded:

```
NSError *_error;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&_error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", _error, [_error userInfo]);
}
```

and if I set that piece of code into a separate method and then call that method in viewDidLoad in background

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(fetchIt) withObject:nil];
```

tableView is just not updating, so I have to go back to the first tableView and then come back to get any results.

Thank you.

Any help would be appreciated

**update**

I did try a few other ways to do it.

Way 1:

```
-(void)reloadTheTable
{
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)fetchIt
{
  NSError *_error;
  if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&_error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", _error, [_error userInfo]);
  }
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTheTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
  [pool release];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  //some code
  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(fetchIt) withObject:nil];
  //some other code
}
```

result: tableView doesn't show any data, need to re-open that view controller

Way 2:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  //some code
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSError *_error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&_error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", _error, [_error userInfo]);
    }
  });
  //some other code
}
```

result: tableView updates, but UI freezes

Way 3:

```
-(void)fetchIt
{
  NSError *_error;
  if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&_error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", _error, [_error userInfo]);
  }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  //some code
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchIt) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
  //some other code
}
```

result: UI freezes, table view updates.

As I read somewhere, everything that has to do something with UI must be done on a main thread. But I still can't figure out how to do it without freezing the tableView.

Thank you for reading.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think you are looking for [THIS](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: @Kjuly thanks, but it still is kinda unresponsive. Using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... });

Comment: Don't use `dispatch_get_main_queue` this will block your app either, as the UI run in main thread, you need to fetch data in other threads.

Comment: @Kjuly I did try both dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0) and dispatch_queue_create(nil, nil), but the tableView just doesn't update

Comment: @Novary update tableView? Try `[tableView reloadData];`. :)

Comment: @Kjuly tried that a few times, doesn't work :S

Comment: @Kjuly just tried     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ ... });, tableView updates, but it still freezes

Comment: Hi @Novarg, does it work now? If not, please paste your code in your question.

Comment: @Kjuly hi, nope, it doesn't work yet the way I want it to. I updated the question, thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this'll work or not, but you can have a try:

```
- (void)methodThatloadYourData {
  NSError *_error;
  if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&_error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", _error, [_error userInfo]);
  }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  //some code

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),
                 ^{
                   [self performSelector:@selector(methodThatloadYourData)];
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                    ^{
                                      [self.tableView reloadData];
                                    });
                 });

  //some other code
}
```

Comment: I used this for similar issue. It works as expected except that when the table reloads it is BLAM, all the records appear at once somewhat abruptly. I think I flinched the first time I saw this it surprise me that much. Can anyone think of a way to make them flow a bit more organically into place without scaring the user?

Comment: @DeanDavids you can create a method (e.g. `reloadDataAnimated:(BOOL)animated`) with fade animation & put `[self.tableView reloadData];` into this method. Then use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self reloadDataAnimated:YES]; });` I have not tried, just a suggestion. :)

Comment: Downvoted. This is an old answer but this is completely wrong. This will return in Threading issues with NSManagedObjectContext. Turn on Multithreading log and you will get CoreData`+[NSManagedObjectContext __Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__]:.

Answer (score 2):

Set the fetch request's [`fetchBatchSize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/fetchBatchSize) so that you're not actually fetching all the data at once. You probably only need enough records to fill the screen, plus some more to keep initial scrolling responsive. If the data in question is, say, chat messages, I'd think that limiting the fetch to the most recent 50 or 100 messages should speed things up considerably.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it's already only fetching last 50

Answer (score 1):

Once the fetch is done in `fetchIt` method, call the `reloadData` method in `UITableView`. For more reference, see Apple documentation on [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**Edit:**

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

For more info, visit the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Can you please tell me from where you are reloading the table?

Comment: I put it in as the last line of "fetchIt" method. The whole method looks like that: -(void)fetchIt{
    NSError *_error;
 if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&_error]) {
  NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", _error, [_error userInfo]);
 }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

Comment: Implement `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` and implement the method as in Edited part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dispatch your fetch request onto a new thread:

```
dispatch_queue_t coreDataThread = dispatch_queue_create("com.YourApp.YourThreadName", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    dispatch_async(YourThreadName, ^{

Your Fetch Request

    });

    dispatch_release(YourThreadName);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but tableView doesn't reload unless I re-open that view controller

Answer (score 0):

First of all, index your entity properties properly so the queries run faster, especially if sorting. Then look at optimising your fetch request, by setting batch size, limiting the data to the bare minimum necessary. Use the SQL debugger to examine the query, and even test the queries agains the sqlite file yourself using an app like Base. If you try to use multi-threading unnecssarily for such a simple app it will only make matters worse.

FYI in your code, viewDidLoad is already on the main thread. If you are trying to delay the fetch until after the view is loaded then you can use performSelector afterDelay:0.